# How can I determine which files have high I/O in Windows?

Tags: windows, performance, storage, io

In trying to reduce the storage bottleneck on a Windows server (2008 R2) I need to find the files that have the highest I/O over a long period of time (aka 'hot' files) so I can move those to SSD storage. How can I track the I/O of the file system over a longer period of time (i.e. days to weeks) so I can see which files would benefit most from the move?

The Sysinternals utility procmon allows me to gather I/O statistics for short periods (i.e. from seconds to many minutes), but I don't think it's suitable for long term logging.

I would prefer a built-in solution, but will consider any others as well.

Comment: Turns out the performance monitor generates a lot of data (35GB in 12h for me) so may not be suitable for machines low on resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Performance Toolkit which is included in the ADK can log many performance metrics over an extended period of time, including per-file I/O statistics.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526740